# .NET MVC WebApi - Global message handler excluding a specific controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a few controllers and a few methods decorated with a [Route] attribute.
Now the thing is, i want to add a global message handler excluding one single controller.

here is a snapshot from the http configuration code:+
[image: HttpConfiguration]

The problem is, my Free controller (defined in the FreeApi route) is still getting the Custom message handler somehow in the pipeline.

How can i achieve this kind of behavior?

Thanks!